# Remoting objects and remote connections

Tags: c#, remoting

I'm using .NET remoting for some simple observer-based IPC. I've been having two problems:

1. If I don't make any calls from the client on a remote object for a few minutes, an error is thrown when I do try to call, specifying that the connection has been dropped. How can I keep this alive?
2. I can't seem to accept clients from other computers over TCP. I'm using a TcpChannel configured as such:

   ```
   BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider serverProv = new 
       BinaryServerFormatterSinkProvider();
   serverProv.TypeFilterLevel = TypeFilterLevel.Full;
   BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider clientProv = new 
       BinaryClientFormatterSinkProvider();
   IDictionary props = new Hashtable();
   props["port"] = port;
   TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel( props, clientProv, serverProv );

   ChannelServices.RegisterChannel( channel, false );

   RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType( typeof( Controller ),
       "Controller", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton );
   ```

And when a client app tries to connect `( m_Controller = (Controller)RemotingServices.Connect( typeof( Controller ), "tcp://" + ip + ":2594/Controller" ) )`, it always times out. I am not behind a firewall and my ports are forwarded properly. I can use this port for socket-based apps but not for remoting for some reason. Please help!

Comment: Note that using localhost for the IP works fine. It's just connecting from a remote computer that messes up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you initialized the Controller object's lifetime?  See http://www.diranieh.com/NETRemoting/InDepthRemoting.htm.
2. See my answer in here: [Remoting connection over TCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719576/remoting-connection-over-tcp/719630#719630).